# Replacing foldr with foldl

Tags: haskell

I have this function to sum the odd numbers on a list:

```
idOdd xs = foldr (\x acc -> if odd x then x+acc else acc) 0 xs
```

if i want to do it with foldl, how would it change?

Comment: @bheklilr yeah sorry!

Comment: What did you try? Can you share some attempt so that we can prod you in the right direction? Disclosing the solution is hardly useful...

Answer (score 4):

In your case it's very easy, you can just swap the order of the arguments to get it to work correctly:

```
idOdd2 = foldl (\acc x -> if odd x then x + acc else acc) 0
```

This is primarily because your accumulator type is the same as your list element type, and because `+` is commutative and associative.  This is important due to how `foldl` and `foldr` reduce a list:

```
isOdd [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = 1 + (3 + (5 + 0)) = 9

isOdd2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = ((0 + 1) + 3) + 5 = 9
```

In this case `1 + (3 + (5 + 0)) == ((0 + 1) + 3) + 5`, but this isn't true of all operators, such as `:` or `++`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the lambda's signature, since it should first take the accumulator and then the list element:

```
idOdd2 xs = foldl  (\acc x -> if odd x then x+acc else acc) 0 xs
```

Allways use `:t <function>` if you are unsure how to use `function`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can implement foldr using foldl and vice versa.  For example:

```
foldr' f e xs = foldl (flip f) e (reverse xs)
```